# Pagination stock log page

Tags: php

I'm using the stock manager plugin for Woo.
Problem is that there is a lack of support , so I try to fix some problems myself.
But now I'm stuck with pagination.
I do only see 100 products , and on the bottom of the page there is no pagination visible , like it was in an earlier version. (I have over 500 active products)
For me there are two possible solutions : or there is pagination per 100 products , or I can see al products on one page.

The code used

```
<?php
/**
 * Stock Log page.
 *
 * @package  woocommerce-stock-manager/admin/views/
 * @version  2.8.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

$stock = $this->stock();

?>

<div class="wrap">
    <h2><?php echo esc_html( get_admin_page_title() ); ?></h2>
    <div class="t-col-12">
        <div class="toret-box box-info">
            <div class="box-header">
                <h3 class="box-title"></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">
                <div class="clear"></div>
                    <table class="table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Product ID', 'woocommerce-stock-manager' ); ?></th>
                            <th><?php esc_html_e( 'SKU', 'woocommerce-stock-manager' ); ?></th>
                            <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Name', 'woocommerce-stock-manager' ); ?></th>
                            <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Product type', 'woocommerce-stock-manager' ); ?></th>
                            <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Parent ID', 'woocommerce-stock-manager' ); ?></th>
                            <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Stock', 'woocommerce-stock-manager' ); ?></th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                            $get = ( ! empty( $_GET ) ) ? wc_clean( wp_unslash( $_GET ) ) : array(); // phpcs:ignore
                            $products = ( ! empty( $get ) ) ? $stock->get_products( $get ) : array();
                        if ( ! empty( $products->posts ) ) {
                            foreach ( $products->posts as $item ) {
                                $item_product = wc_get_product( $item->ID );
                                if ( ! $item_product instanceof WC_Product ) {
                                    continue;
                                }
                                $product_type = $item_product->get_type();
                                ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="td_center"><?php echo esc_html( $item_product->get_id() ); ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo esc_html( $item_product->get_sku() ); ?></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url() . 'post.php?post=' . $item_product->get_id() . '&action=edit' ); ?>" target="_blank">
                                        <?php echo wp_kses_post( get_the_title( $item_product->get_id() ) ); ?>  
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="td_center"><?php echo esc_html( $product_type ); ?></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td class="td_center"><?php echo esc_html( $item_product->get_stock_quantity() ); ?></td>
                                        <td class="td_center">
                                    <?php if ( 'variable' !== $product_type ) { ?>
                                                <a class="btn btn-success" href="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url() . 'admin.php?page=stock-manager-log&product-history=' . $item_product->get_id() ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'History', 'woocommerce-stock-manager' ); ?></a>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php
                                    if ( 'variable' === $product_type ) {
                                        $args = array(
                                            'post_parent' => $item->ID,
                                            'post_type'   => 'product_variation',
                                            'numberposts' => -1,
                                            'post_status' => 'publish',
                                            'order_by'    => 'menu_order',
                                        );

                                        $variations_array = $item_product->get_children();
                                        foreach ( $variations_array as $vars ) {
                                            $item_product = wc_get_product( $vars );
                                            if ( ! $item_product instanceof WC_Product ) {
                                                continue;
                                            }
                                            $product_type = 'product variation';
                                            ?>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="td_center"><?php echo esc_html( $item_product->get_id() ); ?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo esc_html( $item_product->get_sku() ); ?></td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url() . 'post.php?post=' . $item_product->get_parent_id() . '&action=edit' ); ?>" target="_blank">
                                                        <?php echo wp_kses_post( get_the_title( $item_product->get_id() ) ); ?>  
                                                        </a>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="td_center"><?php echo esc_html( $product_type ); ?></td>
                                                    <td class="td_center"><?php echo esc_html( $item->ID ); ?></td>
                                                    <td class="td_center"><?php echo esc_html( $item_product->get_stock_quantity() ); ?></td>
                                                    <td class="td_center">
                                                        <a class="btn btn-success" href="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url() . 'admin.php?page=stock-manager-log&product-history=' . $item_product->get_id() ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'History', 'woocommerce-stock-manager' ); ?></a>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <?php
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                    </table>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <?php echo wp_kses_post( $stock->pagination( $products ) ); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php
```